# Scrapy start_urls too long / Unsupported URL Scheme

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a problem with my Scrapy Spider which repots an "Unsupported URL Scheme".
I want a scrape a page with search results on it. My Spider fails all the time, because of this long dynamic URL.

```
class RadioSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'radio'
    allowed_domains = ['dashitradio.de']
    start_urls = ["[http://www.dashitradio.de/nc/search-in-playlist.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5BSTART%5D=2013-06-17%2006:00&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5BEND%5D=2013-06-21%2018:00&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bsubmit%5D=Suchen&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bshowpage%5D%5B3%5D=1][1]"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = RadioItem()

        i['title'] = hxs.select("//*[@id='playlist-results']/table//tr[1]/td[1]/text()").extract()
        i['interpret'] = hxs.select("//*[@id='playlist-results']/table[1]//tr/td[2]/text()").extract()
        i['date'] = hxs.select("//*[@id='playlist-results']/table//tr[1]/td[3]/text()").extract()

        return i
```

If I run it in a Scrapy Shell Console it works fine only with inverted commas besides of the URL, like `"URL"`.

How can I have Scrapy accept this String as a single URL inside my Spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start_urls` setting is incorrect: `[` at the beginning and `][1]` at the end make it an invalid url.

I've updated the code of the spider according to your comments:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class RadioItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    interpret = Field()
    date = Field()


class RadioSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'radio'
    allowed_domains = ['dashitradio.de']
    start_urls = ["http://www.dashitradio.de/nc/search-in-playlist.html?tx_wfqbe_pi1%5BSTART%5D=2013-06-17%2006:00&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5BEND%5D=2013-06-21%2018:00&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bsubmit%5D=Suchen&tx_wfqbe_pi1%5Bshowpage%5D%5B3%5D=1"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        rows = hxs.select("//div[@id='playlist-results']/table/tbody/tr")
        for row in rows:
            item = RadioItem()

            item['title'] = row.select(".//td[1]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['interpret'] = row.select(".//td[2]/text()").extract()[0]
            item['date'] = row.select(".//td[3]/text()").extract()[0]

            yield item
```

Save it into `my_spider.py` and run via `runspider`:

```
scrapy runspider my_spider.py -o output.json
```

And you'll see in the `output.json`:

```
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:48:00", "interpret": "MUMFORD & SONS", "title": "I WILL WAIT"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:44:00", "interpret": "TASMIN ARCHER", "title": "SLEEPING SATELLITE"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:40:03", "interpret": "ROBIN THICKE", "title": "BLURRED LINES (feat. T.I. & PHARRELL)"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:35:02", "interpret": "TINA TURNER", "title": "TWO PEOPLE"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:31:02", "interpret": "BON JOVI", "title": "WHAT ABOUT NOW"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:28:03", "interpret": "ROXETTE", "title": "SHE'S GOT NOTHING ON (BUT THE RADIO)"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:18:01", "interpret": "GNARLS BARKLEY", "title": "CRAZY"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:08:01", "interpret": "FLO RIDA", "title": "WHISTLE"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:05:03", "interpret": "WHAM", "title": "WAKE ME UP BEFORE YOU GO GO"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 17:00:03", "interpret": "P!NK FEAT. NATE RUESS", "title": "JUST GIVE ME A REASON"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 16:48:01", "interpret": "SHAKIRA", "title": "WHENEVER, WHEREVER"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 16:44:00", "interpret": "ALPHAVILLE", "title": "BIG IN JAPAN"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 16:40:01", "interpret": "XAVIER NAIDOO", "title": "BEI MEINER SEELE"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 16:36:02", "interpret": "SANTANA", "title": "SMOOTH"}
{"date": "2013-06-21 16:32:01", "interpret": "OLLY MURS", "title": "ARMY OF TWO"}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If i do remove ' on both sides of the URL i would habe as result a clear .json file without any data in it. I tried it before i post a Question here. I think, without ' scrapy do not accept my long url and do split it into parts because of many parameter inside of it.

Comment: It should work. Could you post the whole code of your spider?

Comment: i edited it, should i post the rest, where i define xpath elements also?

Comment: It would be great, so I can reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Im newbee in scrapy & python. Firstly i just wanted to try to scrap a tracklist from a first page of results and drop it into a json file.